# Xcode 6.1 Swift Thread 1 Sigabrt Error

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6.1

> 2015-04-14 23:35:17.143 Yellow Ninja 2.0[12492:594324]
>   -[Yellow_Ninja_2_0.ACWallGenerator generatewall]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7faf38fb7ce0 2015-04-14 23:35:17.146
>   Yellow Ninja 2.0[12492:594324] *** Terminating app due to uncaught
>   exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   '-[Yellow_Ninja_2_0.ACWallGenerator generatewall]: unrecognized
>   selector sent to instance 0x7faf38fb7ce0'
>   *** First throw call stack: (     0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010fc77f35 **exceptionPreprocess + 165  1   libobjc.A.dylib
>
>   0x0000000111bb4bb7 objc_exception_throw + 45  2   CoreFoundation
>
>   0x000000010fc7f04d -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] +
>   205   3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010fbd727c
>   ___forwarding_** + 988    4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010fbd6e18 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120  5   Foundation
>   0x00000001102ef2b4 **NSFireTimer + 83     6   CoreFoundation
>
>   0x000000010fbdff64
>   __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION** + 20    7   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010fbdfb25
>   __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 1045     8   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010fba2e5d __CFRunLoopRun + 1901    9   CoreFoundation
>   0x000000010fba2486 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470     10  GraphicsServices
>   0x00000001170249f0 GSEventRunModal + 161  11  UIKit
>   0x00000001108fc420 UIApplicationMain + 1282   12  Yellow Ninja 2.0
>   0x000000010fa7a5be top_level_code + 78    13  Yellow Ninja 2.0
>   0x000000010fa7a5fa main + 42  14  libdyld.dylib
>   0x00000001123a0145 start + 1  15  ???
>   0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1 ) libc++abi.dylib: terminating with
>   uncaught exception of type NSException (lldb)

This is the error message that came up whenever I try to run my app. Any suggestions please? It says "InvalidArgumentException"??? Thanks!

Comment: check your selector method format, it having some parameter or only simple one. and also check If you are using delegate to call that method so the delegate is nil or not....

Comment: check this : http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1

Answer (score 0):

You have set up a timer to call `generatewall` when it fires. But either you have no `generatewall` method — for example, if it takes a parameter, then it is called `generatewall:`, with a colon — or you have neglected to expose that method to Objective-C.

Comment: And see the discussion in my book: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/apa.html#_selectors